# Transactional replication from Oracle PL/SQL to MS SQL Server broke from the data in a Date column but previous records with same date are ok?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, oracle-12c, transactional-replication

I have a heterogenous transactional replication subscription setup between PL/SQL (12C 12.1.0.1.0) and SQL Server (2008 R2), where the Oracle PL/SQL server is the publisher and the MS SQL server is the subscriber.

I have an alert setup on the MS SQL server for replication failures, and today the replication failed with the following error:

> DESCRIPTION: Replication-Replication Transaction-Log Reader Subsystem:
>   agent OracleServer/OracleServer-OracleServer/OracleServer-37 failed.
>   An error occurred for column 'DATE31', when processing changes for
>   article 'PAGE_THREE', of publication
>   'OracleServer_Transaction_Replication'.

I was able to determine the source record of the issue by sorting on an updated date column on my MS SQL server and looking at the updated date and record ID and then comparing to the same type of query on my Oracle PL/SQL server to find the next record that didn't get replicated. I then added a filter on the publication object on my MS SQL Server to filter out that problematic record's record ID. This caused my transactional replication to start working as normal again.

What I don't understand is the DATE31 column (it's PL/SQL datatype "DATE") of the problematic record has the same exact date in it as the last non-problematic record before it (the one that replicated fine.)

(Don't mind the aliases):
[image: Oracle PL/SQL Server Query]

Record #7 above (ID = 61216226) is a good record that replicated over.
Record #6 (ID = 61215965) is the bad record that broke replication and caused the error I quoted above.
All the other fields for these two records in this table are null, so it's definitely this DATE31 column that's the issue.

What gives?

Comment: Post `dump(DATE31)` of those two rows.

Comment: DUMP(DATE31) returned the following for both rows: Typ=12 Len=7: 120,150,12,31,1,1,1